# What are some creative ways to panic kernel? Also, is there any way to cause a piece of kernel code panic?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to test the kernel by causing a kernel panic. I tried with a panic module, but that option isn't very effective as I can't really keep a trace of the panic.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `panic` function in the kernel:

```
    panic("DON'T PANIC!\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should issue the command:

```sh
sudo bash -c 'echo "c" > /proc/sysrq-trigger'
```

Comment: If possible, I want to write an external module to cause a kernel panic.